# How to generate .trx file in vs2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 Ultimate edition for my Coded UI project.

My project is not generating .trx file in the TestResults folder. Please suggest me steps to get .trx file using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 11):

VS 2012 does not generate .trx files and there is not a way to configure it to do so. However, if you use [VSTest.Console.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) command line utility, then you can generate a .trx file by passing it /logger:trx command line parameter.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer how to do it?

Comment: Well you need to run your tests using VSTest.Console.exe with logger parameter along with others in command line instead of VS. If you look at the bottom of the link in my post, you should see an example.

Comment: Hi Mehmet, I guess u missed to post ur link :-)

Comment: I don't think so. VSTest.Console.exe in my post is a hyperlink. You can click on it.

Comment: the above stated post has not any link :-)

Comment: You are kidding right? Here it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx

Comment: The parameter should say /logger:trx instead of /logger:txt - MSDN says so and I checked it myself. Stack Overflow won't let me edit the post since they require an edit to be at least 6 characters, but maybe you can do it?

Comment: Done. Thank for noticing and letting me know Grzesiek Galezowski :-)

Comment: In VS2015, when running unit tests in the Test View, I guess it's still not possible to generate .TRX files?